# Are all natural processes that are bigger than a molecule also deterministic?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, determinism

Is there something bigger than a molecule and still random in nature?

I know that the decay of an unstable atom cannot be predicted, only the probability of decay can be calculated. Molecules moving in a fluid also could be random.

But is there anything bigger than that that could be non-deterministic?

Does randomness stop at the molecular level?

Comment: Do you mean quantum randomness?

Comment: I mean a random sequence of events in the mathematical sense. Something without a pattern.

Comment: What about the distribution of galaxies, they are quite big? But when you say _Something without a pattern_  But doesn't every sequence fit some pattern? At least in Physics,  radomness is related to unpredictability/non-determinism.

Answer (score 1):

We have to define what is random here.

If you measure all the incoming photons coming from the sun, they are approximately distributed according to the (random) [radiation of a black body](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_body_radiation) of 5800 K. This process is quite random.

The electron movements around an atom is, from what we know, random as well, given we don't measure it to often (as in Heisenberg's inequality relation).

The question is whether we can measure a certain randomness, and are able to use it in a computation for a poker site or something else. Have a look at how [hardware random number generators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_random_number_generator) does this, it's not trivial at all. Even small skewness in the random distribution could ruin monte carlo calculations, cryptographic algorithms or lotteries.